# Find adjacent/neighboring elements in a list of objects c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of objects. I have a value, that is not in the list, but would like to find the adjacent elements, where that value would fit. Basically the previous and next element,like if this value was part of the list.

```
    var previous = 0;
    var next = 0;
    decimal Value = 45M;

        List<MileStone> items = new List<MileStone>();
                items.Add(new MileStone() { CheckPoint = 0, Distance = 15.4M});// i = 0
                items.Add(new MileStone() { CheckPoint = 20, Distance = 24.8M});// i = 1
                items.Add(new MileStone() { CheckPoint = 40, Distance = 39.7M});// i = 2
                items.Add(new MileStone() { CheckPoint = 60, Distance = 59.3M});// i = 3
                items.Add(new MileStone() { CheckPoint = 80, Distance = 80.1M});// i = 4
```

In this example the 'Value' = 45, so that would fit between items[2] and item[3].
Desired outcome would be, a new list of the neighboring values:

```
List<MileStone> items2 = new List<MileStone>();
items2.Add(items[2]);
items2.Add(items[3]);
```

If 'Value' = 10 there should be only a one element in the items2 list, because there is no previous case.

```
List<MileStone> items2 = new List<MileStone>();
items2.Add(items[0]);
```

I would like to find an elegant, and nice solution for this, using LINQ Lambda expression.

I can find the indexes with a for loop, then add the desired elements to the items2 list, but would like to find a LINQ approach.

Any idea is welcomed!
Thanks!

Comment: "I can find the indexes with a for loop" and it would probably be 1 the most readable solution, 2 the most efficient solution allowing you to bailout early. Do you really need LINQ in this case?

Comment: The most efficient solution would be binary search, not an O(n) iteration over the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Linq, one way to do this would be to order the list by the `Distance` property, then find the last item with a distance less than `Value` and the first item with a distance greater than `Value`, and add them to a List.

Here's a helper method that does that:

```
private static List<MileStone> GetNeighboringItems(decimal value, 
    List<MileStone> milestones)
{
    var neighbors = new List<MileStone>();
    if (milestones == null || milestones.Count == 0) return neighbors;

    var orderedList = milestones.OrderBy(m => m.Distance).ToList();

    var lesser = orderedList.LastOrDefault(m => m.Distance < value);
    var greater = orderedList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Distance > value);

    if (lesser != null) neighbors.Add(lesser);
    if (greater != null) neighbors.Add(greater);

    return neighbors;
}
```

Then you can get your "neighbors" for `Value = 45` and `Value = 10`:

```
private static void Main()
{
    List<MileStone> items = new List<MileStone>
    {
        new MileStone {CheckPoint = 0, Distance = 15.4M},
        new MileStone {CheckPoint = 20, Distance = 24.8M},
        new MileStone {CheckPoint = 40, Distance = 39.7M},
        new MileStone {CheckPoint = 60, Distance = 59.3M},
        new MileStone {CheckPoint = 80, Distance = 80.1M}
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Neighbors of 45: {0}",
        string.Join(", ", GetNeighboringItems(45, items)));

    Console.WriteLine("Neighbors of 10: {0}",
        string.Join(", ", GetNeighboringItems(10, items)));

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

**Note**

I overrode `ToString` on the `MileStone` class so the `Distance` is shown for each item when written to the console:

```
public class MileStone
{
    public int CheckPoint { get; set; }
    public decimal Distance { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Distance.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code orders the items twice, you can `ToList` the result of `OrderBy` to avoid that.

Comment: During LastOrDefault and during FirstOrDefault, a new enumerator will be created for each case

Comment: Oh, thanks! I added your suggestion. I have to remember that.